# Как получить доступ к MeshTextPro в unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

в 2d игре на unity пишет такую ошибку при попытке подключения к TextMeshPro через c# код
TextMeshPro в UI
unity 2020

Мне нужно получить сам текст и изменить его

[image: Текст]

```cs
public class ExampleText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI Textik;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

всё оказалось проще
нужно добавить using TMPro;
и тогда это работает правильно
полный список using:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
```

Comment: Только `using TMPro;`